# Error download from Yahoo finance

Tags: vba, excel, yahoo-finance

On 16th May 2017 yahoo.finance change the url to download the Eod Price. I try to use the new Url but it doesn't work.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
       "TEXT;https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/APPL?period1=946854000&period2=1495234800&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=" + mycrumb  _
       , Destination:=Range("Dati!$A$2"))
       .Name = "Data Table"
       .FieldNames = True
       .RowNumbers = False
       .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
       .PreserveFormatting = True
       .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
       .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
       .SavePassword = False
       .SaveData = True
       .AdjustColumnWidth = True
       .RefreshPeriod = 0
       .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
       .TextFilePlatform = 850
       .TextFileStartRow = 1
       .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
       .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
       .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
       .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
       .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
       .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
       .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
       .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9)
       .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
       .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

May someone help me to solve my problem? Have someone the same problem?
Thanks a lot

Andrea

Comment: "...but it doesn't work."  What's not working? The site isn't accessible, you get a VBA error, the data loads but it's incorrect data, etc....?

Comment: I recommend using the Alpha Vantage stock data API now. It works really well.

I've just written a blog post about it: http://www.the-data-wrangler.com/acquiring-stock-market-data-from-alpha-vantage/

Answer (score 1):

First, the old Yahoo finance iChart download is gone for good. In one of the forum posts, a Yahoo employee has confirmed that the free EOD data has been terminated, and will not be reintroduced. Check out this [thread](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Is-Yahoo-Finance-API-broken/td-p/250503/page/3) and look for reply from Nixon. Yahoo is recently acquired by Verizon, and it must be the new direction.

However, if you check the Yahoo financial page, the CSV download link works, though differently now. It is through a new API that uses an authentication token "crumb" that is linked to a cookie when you access the page.

Your code is using this new API, so you must get the correct matching pairs of cookie and crumb. I have put together some quick Python3 code to do that (and to download the same CSV as before) through this new API. Please check out GitHub for source code [yahoo_quote_download](https://github.com/c0redumb/yahoo_quote_download).

Comment: Do you know any way to download data from vba? or obtain the crumb for vba? thanks

Comment: Sorry, you will have to adopt the code to VBA yourself. I think it should work based on the same principle.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem since May.  Came up with this code yesterday:

```
Sub YahooHistDataHoriztl()
 '---enter in cell A1 for daily:   _https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?interval=1d
 '---enter in cell A1 for weekly:  _https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?interval=1wk 
 '---enter in cell A1 for DOW weekly:  _https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/^DJI/history?interval=1wk

 '--- Historical Data will load in columns D through J
 '---This program developed after watching video from 'Automate the Web' 2017-07-03
 '---Use Excel & VBA to automate Internet Explorer -beginner
 '----_https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRuzoI_kihI&index=3&list=PL0bsMa4HWk9synJWmuqZmI4Z0a3eurN7V
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
Dim y As Integer 'integer variable used as a counter for Rows
Dim z As Integer 'integer variable used as a counter for Columns
Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link
Dim Pather As String
Dim CurrActiveBook As String
Dim CurrActiveSheet As String
Dim drV As String
Dim targetBook As String

 'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Pather = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"   '---holds current path---
  ChDrive Pather                      '---sets excel to the current drive---
  ChDir Pather                       '---sets excel to the current drive---
  drV = Left(Pather, 3)
  CurrActiveBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
  CurrActiveSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
   targetBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
   Range("D2:K62").Select
    Selection.ClearContents         '---clears old data

   Set objIE = New InternetExplorer      'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
    objIE.Visible = False      'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
    objIE.navigate Sheets(CurrActiveSheet).Range("A1").Value      'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
     Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop     'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
      Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")  '---Give an extra 5 seconds to upload

  Range("D1") = "Date"
  Range("E1") = "Open"
  Range("F1") = "High"
  Range("G1") = "Low"
  Range("H1") = "Close"
  Range("I1") = "Adj Close*"
  Range("J1") = "Avg Vol"

  Range("D2").Select
    y = 0   'the first search result will go in row 2
    z = 0
   For Each aEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("Py(10px)")   'for each <a> element in the collection of objects with class of 'result__a'...
      ActiveCell.Offset(y, z).Value = aEle.innerText
        Debug.Print aEle.innerText

 If z > 5 Then   '---Data loads in one column.  This converts to a table.-------
    z = 0
    y = y + 1   'increment our row counter, so the next result goes below
   Application.Wait Now + (TimeValue("0:00:01") / 2) '--giver data an extra 1/2 second to load up---
Else
    If z = 1 Then
     If Right(ActiveCell.Offset(y, z), 5) = "Split" Then   '---Split reset back to date column---
        z = 0
        y = y + 1
         Else
           If Right(ActiveCell.Offset(y, z), 8) = "Dividend" Then   '---Dividend reset back to date column---
            z = 0
            y = y + 1
           Else
         z = z + 1
        End If
      End If
    Else
      z = z + 1
    End If
  End If
   DoEvents
  Next  'repeat times the # of ele's we have in the collection

objIE.Quit      'close the browser
Columns("D:J").Select
 Selection.Columns.AutoFit
  Range("D1").Select

      Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     MsgBox "Done"
   End Sub '---End of program---
```

Comment: It's unclear whether this code is a solution, or you are talking, you have the same problem with it. In the first case update your answer, in the second - ask in a separate question.